# multiple integrals in the same variable in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, numerical, integral

I need to evaluate the following integral in MATLAB (numerically):
[image]

I already tried various things but I can't figure out how to solve this! Following is my last try:

```
Fdx = @(x) integral(@(y)1./(1+sqrt(y.^2))*(1-pi^2),0,x);
dFdx(1)
F = 8 * integral(dFdx,0,10)
```

As a result MATLAB gives me this error message:

> Error using integral (line 85)
>   A and B must be floating-point scalars.
>
> Error in @(x)integral(@(y)1./(1+sqrt(y.^2))*(1-pi^2),0,x)
>
> Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 314)
>                   fx = FUN(t);
>
> Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 132)
>               [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);
>
> Error in integralCalc (line 75)
>           [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@AtoBInvTransform,interval);
>
> Error in integral (line 88)
>   Q = integralCalc(fun,a,b,opstruct);
>
> Error in test (line 7)
>   F=8 * integral(dFdx,0,10)

Comment: The integrand does not depend on x, so you can change the order of the integrals, do the x integration analytically and be lect with a single integral.

Answer (score 2):

Try using  `integral2` instead. See example 2 in the documentation:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral2.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: Not sure how to adjust this to my problem because the boundary of the inner interal is dependent on the outer integral

Comment: @chi86 And the first two examples show how to handle that.

Comment: @chi86 As i said, see example 2. It shows the case you want.